# translate angular datatable headers

Tags: angularjs, translate

i am trying to  integrate angular datatable with angular translate since i needed translated values in header and in some cases for column values also.I tried to add translated headers by using $translate function.but it is taking time to resolve the promise.In such situations the header columns become empty.To avoid that i added the grid options configurations inside the translate promise success function.Then in some times it is not working properly.if any one have some idea to resolve this please help.Advanced thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is not backed by any code, which makes it very difficult for anyone to help you. Please take the time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

[In this article](http://technpol.wordpress.com/2013/09/03/crud-application-with-angularjs-rails-twitter-bootstrap-and-ng-boilerplate-part-6-another-entity/), the author faces some issues with angular-translate and the column headers of a ngGrid (in the second half of the article).
 Even if this does not hit 100% your case, it might give you some hint on how to approach the problem.